# Phoronix vs Sysbench benchmarks

Tags: cpu, performance, benchmarking

I have 3  x86 xeon machines [with RHEL 7.4], machines are using Haswell, Broadwell and Skylake based CPUs.

When I run prime number calculation using sysbench [using varying number of threads], I get better results with Skylake based machine. But when I ran the following benchmarks using Phoronix suite, I see 30-40% lesser stats on the Skylake machine, while Haswell and Broadwell perform as expected [i.e broadwell performs better than Haswell]:

- Fast Fourier Transform
- Successive Over Relaxation
- Monte Carlo Performance
- Bork File Encryption
- SunFlow Rendering

The same version of Phoronix test suite is running on all 3 machines.

Why is a Skylake machine performing better with prime numbers calculation while performing decisively slower in other comprehensive tests?

Comment: Do you have power saving profile set to Performance on Skylake machine? So it always runs at full speed. Are frequencies comparable? HT on/off on all nodes?

Comment: All machines running with default BIOS/EFI settings. Default power profiles. Frequencies are different. HT is on all nodes. But the performance drop is too bad on Skylake, though it's a dual socket Platinum 8160 Xeon CPU